# JSON length in javascript returns number of character instead of number of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, wordpress

Hi I have problem and I tried similar things and answer but neither Object.keys(data).length doesn't help me. Here is my JSON

```
{
    "POSTS": [
        [
            {
                "term_id": 1,
                "name": "Uncategorized",
                "slug": "uncategorized",
                "term_group": 0,
                "term_taxonomy_id": 1,
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "count": 1,
                "filter": "raw",
                "cat_ID": 1,
                "category_count": 1,
                "category_description": "",
                "cat_name": "Uncategorized",
                "category_nicename": "uncategorized",
                "category_parent": 0
            },
            {
                "term_id": 2,
                "name": "Nova",
                "slug": "nova",
                "term_group": 0,
                "term_taxonomy_id": 2,
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "count": 1,
                "filter": "raw",
                "cat_ID": 2,
                "category_count": 1,
                "category_description": "",
                "cat_name": "Nova",
                "category_nicename": "nova",
                "category_parent": 0
            },
            {
                "term_id": 3,
                "name": "nova1",
                "slug": "nova1",
                "term_group": 0,
                "term_taxonomy_id": 3,
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "count": 1,
                "filter": "raw",
                "cat_ID": 3,
                "category_count": 1,
                "category_description": "",
                "cat_name": "nova1",
                "category_nicename": "nova1",
                "category_parent": 0
            },
            {
                "term_id": 4,
                "name": "nova2",
                "slug": "nova2",
                "term_group": 0,
                "term_taxonomy_id": 4,
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 3,
                "count": 1,
                "filter": "raw",
                "cat_ID": 4,
                "category_count": 1,
                "category_description": "",
                "cat_name": "nova2",
                "category_nicename": "nova2",
                "category_parent": 3
            },
            {
                "term_id": 5,
                "name": "nova3",
                "slug": "nova3",
                "term_group": 0,
                "term_taxonomy_id": 5,
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 3,
                "count": 1,
                "filter": "raw",
                "cat_ID": 5,
                "category_count": 1,
                "category_description": "",
                "cat_name": "nova3",
                "category_nicename": "nova3",
                "category_parent": 3
            }
        ]
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

And here is my javascript code :

```
<select id ="new" name="new"></select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var select = document.getElementById("new");
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/ajax.php", // this script returns my JSON 
             data: ({canum: 0}), 
             success: function(data){
                 console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
             }
        });
   });
</script>
```

This returns me 1445 as length not 5 as I need, how to get number of segments in `JSON` how to get 5 instead of number of characters ?

Can you help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Your json will just be a string until you parse it, right? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 7):

You need to `JSON.parse` the data. In your case it is not sent as `application/json`, it is being sent as `text/html`.

Your success function should do something like this:

```
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
}
```

---

**As an alternative,**
you can try this though if you do not want to `JSON.parse` the data and just have jQuery manage it. You can pass the `dataType` you are expecting back from the server in your config object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/ajax.php", // this script returns my JSON 
    data: ({canum: 0}),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
    },
    dataType: 'json' // <- Add this
});
```

Here is the [documentation for `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which talks about the options for that key.

---

**And as one last option,** you can use [$.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead which is a shorthand version of the above.

Comment: As this guy says... the easiest way to parse it is to just add `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax request.

Comment: @KevBot Thank you very much the moment I opened my android app I remembered that I need to do the parsing. Thank you for your solutions and answers.